# Electron density via bosonization/refermionization

Tags: mathematical-physics, fermions, many-body, bosons

I'm currently trying to understand the rigorous construction of [bosonization/refermionization](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275v3) via Jan von Delft.

In the constructive approach, we consider a system on a finite $L$ circle and thus in equation (64), he obtains the refermionization result,
$$
\psi(x) = \frac{F}{a} \exp (-i\Phi(x))
$$
Where $F$ is the Klein factor, $\Phi(x)$ is the a Boson field, and $a\to 0$ is a regularization constant.
Now of course, this isn't quite an equality since $\psi(x)$ isn't quite well-defined. The rigorous result should be considered as
$$
\psi(f)=\lim_{a\to 0}\int_0^L f(x) \frac{F}{a} \exp(-i\Phi (x))"="\int_0^L f(x)\psi(x)dx
$$
Where $\psi$ is a mapping from $L^2[0,L]$ functions on the circle into the operator space, and the $"="$ denote formal notation showing the relations between the two.

Since this a rigorous result, I should be able to compute $\rho(x) \equiv :\psi(x)\psi(x):$ using this refermionization formula (after some way of regularizaing the divergence behaviors such as using $\psi(f)$ as in the previous example), yet I'm not sure how one would do so.

Indeed, it's not to difficult to compute $\rho(x) = \partial \Phi(x)$ as in Eq. (37) just by using the definition of $\Phi(x)$ in Eq. (64), or more rigorously,
$$
\int f(x):\psi^\dagger (x)\psi(x): "="\lim_{a\to 0}\int f(x) \partial \Phi(x), \quad f\in L^2
$$
But it would be nice to see that I could achieve the same result using the refermionization formula.